# Android Studio Gradle Error at Compile Time

Tags: android, gradle

I have an Android App in Android Studio. When I build project with Gradle File,it gives me one error at compile time.
Error Report:

```
Error:org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultFileCollectionSnapshotter$FileCollectionSnapshotImpl cannot be cast to
org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.OutputFilesCollectionSnapshotter$OutputFilesSnapshot
```

Please Give me solution about this error.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

1.delete {project dir}/.gradle/{gradle distribution version dir}

{gradle distribution version dir} is whatever the gradle distribution version you use (ref: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html#revisions). For example, it can be "1.9" or "2.10" or some other version number.

2.Sync Project with Gradle File

Comment: This happened to me because OS got frozen and i forced restart of OS (Android Studio was still opened) and this error occurred.

Comment: It worked for me but I had to invalidate caches after step 3 because I had other errors after step 2.

Comment: I have delete everything under folder .gradle and it fix it

Comment: You sir just saved my Job. I don't have to be homeless and hungry because of you. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

This is what worked for me:

Android Studio -> File -> Invalidate Caches and Restart

Answer (score 2):

Stoping the gradle daemon worked for me.

- go to terminal and run ./gradlew --stop
- Rebuild the project.

Answer (score 1):

For me, I have tried to:

(**Doesn't Work**):

1. invalidate caches.
2. stop third-party plugins.
3. remove gradle repository.
4. remove {project dir}/.gradle/2.*(which are not current gradle version)

(**Work**):

Finally, the answer is like @MAC113's,

**delete {project dir}/.gradle/2.10 (2.10 is my current gradle version)**

Answer (score 0):

None of those solutions working for me. I ended up by:

- Clone my project to a new folder
- Remove .gradle, .idea folders
- Add as a new project (File > Open > [new folder])

It works! It's a weird issue that I've ever met.

Answer (score 0):

Easy solution! Just fixed on my side. It was a project exported from Unity Studio.

After exporting from Unity, the gradle was like com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0

I then changed it to com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0 and it worked.

Also never forget to change the repositories from mavencenteral to jcenter().

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you using GreenDao You should update it to the lastest version

```
classpath 'org.greenrobot:greendao-gradle-plugin:3.3.0' // add plugin
implementation 'org.greenrobot:greendao:3.3.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Deleting .gradle folder works for me