# Android Studio Gradle fails to build

Tags: android, android-studio

I am facing this problem from some few days. 
When I try to build the project gradle thorws this message.
I cleaned the project re downloaded the dependencies but still problem has not be solved.

Help me to find out the fix.

Error message

```
:app:dexDebug
Error:org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultFileCollectionSnapshotter$FileCollectionSnapshotImpl cannot be cast to org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.OutputFilesCollectionSnapshotter$OutputFilesSnapshot
Possible causes for this unexpected error include:<ul><li>Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
<a href="syncProject">Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)</a></li><li>The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
<a href="stopGradleDaemons">Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)</a></li></ul>In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.
```

Comment: Try deleting the gradle cache folder:  `C:\Users\<username>\.gradle\cache`   on Windows, `~/.gradle/cache` on Linux/Mac

Comment: `./gradle --stop` to stop all daemons. Does your project use the gradle wrapper? Then you don't need to use your local gradle install `./gradlew build`

Comment: Being newbie. I actually didn't understand your answer.

would you be please more specific @RiccardoCiovati

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Similar problem like this one：[Similiar question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26354153/android-studio-gradle-error-at-compile-time)

I solved my problem by following that answer. Hope it will help you, too.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Shawlaw. But I fixed this issue earlier and don't even remember what I did. I applied many solution and don't even knaw which one worked.