# Gradle is build with errors in android studio

Tags: java, android

I am using android studio.This is the error suddenly I got when building gradle. Earlier it was working correctly. I close the android studio and re-build the gradle. But doesn't fix the error. I clean and rebuild the gradle.

Can you solve the problem.

```
Error:org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultFileCollectionSnapshotter$FileCollectionSnapshotImpl cannot be cast to org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.OutputFilesCollectionSnapshotter$OutputFilesSnapshot
```

Possible causes for this unexpected error include:

- Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
  Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
- The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
  Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)
- Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.

In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.

Following display my build.gradle information

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
pply plugin: 'com.android.application'
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
minSdkVersion 15
targetSdkVersion 23
versionCode 1
versionName "1.0"

Comment: try to sync the gradle. probably it would help!

Comment: This link has answer for the same. Hope its help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26354153/android-studio-gradle-error-at-compile-time

Answer (score 0):

Gradle may be not found. Try to change gradle version and update it with your gradle version like in project :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

**and this one in module of gradle :**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.yourproject"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 14
        versionName '1.4'
    }
```