# Error:org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I am trying to test an app on my phone. Whenever I build the project I get the following error in Android Studio  2.2.

Error:org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.FileCollectionSnapshotImpl cannot be cast to org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.OutputFilesCollectionSnapshotter$OutputFilesSnapshot
Possible causes for this unexpected error include:

- Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
  Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
- The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
  Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)
- Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.

In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.harshohri.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

I killed java processes by restarting the computer. I deleted the gradle and reinstalled it but still facing the error

Comment: This link has answer for the same. Hope its help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26354153/android-studio-gradle-error-at-compile-time